# Make 3 views visible with a NIPagingScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, nimbus-ios

I am playing around with NIPagingScrollView and I am wondering a couple of things:

- Is it mandatory to return a view that has a width of 320px in pagingScrollView:pageViewForIndex:? If not, is there a way to automatically center the view in a page?
- I would like to display on the right edge and the left edge of the screen a piece of the right and left views of the NIPagingScrollView. Is it possible?

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this works the same way as you'd do for a `UIScrollView`:

1. Set `clipsToBounds` to `NO` on both the `NIPagingScrollView`, as well as it's child `UIScrollView` instance (`pagingScrollView`);
2. Make your `NIPagingScrollView` less than the width of the parent view — 260px worked find for my needs, but adjust this as necessary;

Honestly though, if you're targeting iOS 6 or higher I would suggest using a `UICollectionView` instead of `NIPagingScrollView`. You'll get a lot more flexibility in your layout.